# Remove unwanted packages from downloaded android source before build

Tags: android, android-source

I have downloaded Android 4.0.1_r1 source code to my local system. I'm working to understand building own custom Android ROM and modify it according to my requirements.

I went through a number of web based tutorials on how to build custom ROMs for Android and I am clear with the overall process. What I'm essentially looking for is a well defined structured way of removing packages that are downloaded along with the source code but not needed for my own version of the build.

Additionally, it would be helpful if someone can provide me links pointing to **building android source** (guides,books or tutorials) as most of the available resources are based on *creating Android APPs using Android SDK* and the application framework. Its difficult to find any decent indepth tutorial explaining the entire architecture , source tree and different build guidelines for platform level developers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [good book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do), but it's not officially out yet (you can get the first few chapters only).

There is no real documentation, but if you hang out with CyanogenMod forums/IRC long enough you can get some insights. You can also ask questions on the official [Google Groups](http://source.android.com/community/index.html), android-porting and android-platform should be helpful. Reading XDA can be helpful too, if you can filter out all the noise.

Generally, the whole thing is quite complicated, and there are parts that are device specific. The only thing that you can remove more or less safely without modifying things (much) are the bundled user-level apps (Calculator, etc). Even some of those may provide some system-level services, so you should watch out.

In short, buy the book, read the groups and ask more specific questions, like 'how do I modify X in order to do Y. I tried Z and it didn't quite work.

Comment: Thanks the book happened to be a really good starting point even though it just has only four chapters.

Comment: But even in the book or Google groups, there is no concise mention of how to remove predefined packages from the library.

Comment: This is because such a 'concise' answer is generally impossible. To remove something you need to know what it does, and what other components it interacts with. So unless it doesn't expose any public interface whatsoever, chances are something else depends on it. You need to approach this on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: I agree with you Nikolay on this , however after digging my way around a bit, I figured out that one can remove some apps from buid/target/product/core.mk entries. From concise , I just meant some quick pointers like this file above that can give clue as to where to start looking for. Thanks for your contribution once again.

Comment: Right. However there are device-specific files under device/ that can bring modify this list. Generally, everything that has and Android.mk file is a module and can be removed from build files (with consequences...) You can get a list of modules by running `make modules` in the top directory.

Comment: the link is not working @NikolayElenkov, can you name the book please

Comment: Ha, I don't really remember, but most probably 'Embedded Android' by Karim Yaghmour?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer, this is the closest I got to find a suitable information for modifying packages in the source code before building. It also has a decent information for memory optimization.

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/TI-Android-ICS-MemoryOptimization

For removing packages please refer to the section
Run Time-Volatile Memory Customization
 subsection - Customizing Android Product Package

The article pertains to Froyo , but the concepts are pretty much the same Android 4 ICS.

I have added this for anyone seeking reference material on the same.